# How to draw graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I want to ask questions whether I could draw graphs with these data.

I have dataset looks like below,
(not real data, but it has form of this dataset)

```r
Year 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011
X     0    0    0    1    1    1    1  
Y     0    0    0    0    0    3    3
```

I want to draw a graph with both plot and line, and xaxis with x variable of each year, and Y variable on yaxis.

It is not simply `ggplot(dataset, aes(x=X, y=Y))+geom_point()+geom_line()`

instead I want it to see the number of X in every year on X axis.

Does R offer these kind of function? or do I have to draw seperate graph of year and X and then X and Y?

Thank you so much in advance!

As noted above, I have tried ggplot2 function.

Comment: I am still not quite sure what you're looking for.  You want a plot of X vs Y, but you don't want the x-axis values to be values of X?  Could you explain a bit more what you want the graph to look like?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. on X axis, I want it to be the value of X of each year, and on Y axis, the value of Y. So, I want to see the change of Y in the yearly change of X! For ggplot2, it only gives me the graph of when X value is 0 and 1, but I want it to be 0, 0, 0, 1,1,1,1, and see the time variance of Y align with X.

Comment: maybe drawing 2 y axis (variables for X and Y on each side,) and year on the xaxis..? would I able to draw these kind of graph in R as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a comment, but I will take a bit more space to walk through it since there may be some confusion.

This is a classic example of needing to transform your data from wide to long to visualize it. Assuming you have your data as `dataset`, you can first use `tidy::pivot_longer` to get it in [TIdy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html#:%7E:text=Tidy%20data%20is%20a%20standard,Every%20row%20is%20an%20observation.) format, then plot:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dataset %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Year) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, group = Year)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

The `pivot_longer(-Year)` takes all the columns except `Year` and transforms them to long (run `dataset %>% pivot_longer(-Year)` to see what it does).

The resulting figure looks like this, from which you can customize according to you needs:

[image]

Data:

```
dataset <- read.table(text = "Year 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011
X     0    0    0    1    1    1    1  
Y     0    0    0    0    0    3    3", h = TRUE)
```